# Can't transmit UART signal from Circuit Playground Express to Raspberry Pi witth 433MHz rf link kit

Tags: rf, raspberry-pi, uart, transmitter

I'm a noob on electronics and I've been trying to send data from a Circuit Playground Express to a Raspberry Pi with a 433MHz rf link kit.
I followed a Rasperry Pi tutorial with the rpi_rf.py library and worked well. Later tried rewriting the library to include Circuit Playground Express libraries for digital output instead of the Rpi GPIO, however, although I have made various tests to prove the existence of the data, the receiver is not finding any signal from the transmitter.
Is it possible that the Circuit Playground Express is just not capable of doing this? Or am I just not trying the right way?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please identify the "rf link kit".  What have you done to verify the source signal?  How are you checking the receiver for signal?  If you revert back to the original setup/software does it still work?

Comment: Ah let me see. If you are using SPI rf transceiver, eg. nrFL2401, and Circuit Playground does not have SPI, then using GPIO to fake SPI would be very messy.

Comment: @tlfong01 this does not appear to be about an SPI radio.  It is most certainly not about an nRF24L01 which is a 2.4GHz part because it explicitly says 433 Mhz.  In reality just about everything with 4 GPIOs has SPI, because SPI can be implemented in software.  But in fact the circuit playground both has *and actually makes use of* hardware SPI.  How about we clean up these irrelevancies and wait for the asker to provide the critically missing detail of their specific setup?

Comment: @Esteban Cañas, Or is it RFM12B?

Comment: Hello, [this](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/433Mhz_RF_Link_Kit/) is the rf link kit.To verify signal I put a tester in between the circuit to see if the transmitter was getting current and to see if data was being passed through.